# $ is not defined - asp.net MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

With this code below, I get an error: `$ is not defined`. My question is: How it is possible?

```
...
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#cb').click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('div#div').slideDown();
                } else {
                    $('div#div').slideUp();
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")
```

As we can see, it load properly all of scripts:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You've placed your script in the view body and not inside the `Scripts` section which is where it belongs and **after** referencing jQuery:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#cb').click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('div#div').slideDown();
                } else {
                    $('div#div').slideUp();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Also to avoid having referenced jQuery twice (as in your case) double check if you haven't included it already as a bundle in your `_Layout`.

And one last remark: since by default scripts are included at the end of the DOM, just before the closing body tag, you don't need to be wrapping your script in a `$(document).ready` simply because by the time it executes the DOM will already be loaded. Your code is even worse because you had it twice. Bear in mind that `$(function() { ... });` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` and in your case you've nested 2 of those things when you actually don't need any of them.

So:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#cb').click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('div#div').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('div#div').slideUp();
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: The trick for me was to actually put it inside @sections scripts, not before! thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're not including the jQuery JS until the end of the page but you're trying to make use of $ well before you've included it.

Answer (score 3):

You are including jquery twice.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

The first and the last js files are the same, except one is minified and the other is probably not. Remove the non-minified one and it should work for you.

Comment: it is not a problem - if I include jquery only once, there is the same problem

Comment: You should also load jQuery before loading the jQueryUI library (if you remove min)...